# Hyperledger Queries Tutorial sh:1:eslint: not foud

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am stuck with this error for hours now and cannot find a working solution. I am doing the Queries tutorial on (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/queries.html) but I'm getting this error when I try to run the `npm test` command:

```
sh: 1: eslint: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! my-network@0.1.6 lint: 'eslint .'
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

Any suggestion on how I can fix this errors?

Comment: could you try doing npm install -g eslint and see if that helps ?

Comment: The error says that it cannot find eslint, most probably it is not found in the npm modules, npm install would help solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

npm  -g install eslint would help for all your projects. But in following the Developer tutorial - be aware you need to have all your pre-reqs installed as described here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/installing/development-tools.html  - it mentions a pre-built prereqs script (prereqs-ubuntu.sh) script which you can use or view (if not Ubuntu).